# RESTful web services. Accessing resources

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this restController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UserResourceController extends ResourceController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserResourceController.class);

        @GetMapping(path = "/", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authHeader) {

        User user = authUserOnPath("/users", authHeader);

        user.getApplicationSetup()
                .setExchangeRateWithUSD(currencyService.getUSDRate(user.getApplicationSetup().getAppCcy()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }
}
```

and this other one:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users/wallets")
public class WalletResourceController extends ResourceController {

    @Autowired
    private WalletService walletService;



    /**
     * Get user's wallets
     * 
     * @param request
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping(path = "/", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Wallet>> getUserWallets(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authHeader) {

        User user = authUserOnPath("/users/wallets", authHeader);

        List<Wallet> wallets = userService.getWallets(user);



        return ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)).body(wallets);
    }
```

everything is OK when accessing:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:1133/myApp/api/v1/users
```

but I got a 404 when accessing:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:1133/myApp/api/v1/users/wallets
```

Comment: Are they in different packages? If so, are both packages set up to be scanned by Spring for request mappings?

Comment: they are in the same package

Comment: Try combining them into a single class moving the "wallets" endpoint inside the other RestController and change its Get Mapping to "/wallet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users/wallets")
```

you specified a `GET` endpoint at

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/" ...)
```

So the accessible URL is located at (see terminating `/`)

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:1133/myApp/api/v1/users/wallets/
```